# Why does this C# image handler change the color of my image?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image-processing

I have the below image handler method to resize and save an image, however it changes the image's color enough to notice.  I am passing in 100 as the Quality value.  I also might be losing my mind but i swear on occasion it doesnt affect the colors.  However the last 10 test i ran it did.

```
public string Save(Bitmap image, int maxWidth, int maxHeight, int quality, string pathWithName, out int iWidth, out int iHeight)
    {

        // Get the image's original width and height
        int originalWidth = image.Width;
        int originalHeight = image.Height;
        int newWidth = 0;
        int newHeight = 0;

        if (originalWidth < maxWidth && originalHeight < maxHeight)
        {
            newWidth = originalWidth;
            newHeight = originalHeight;

        }
        else
        {
            // To preserve the aspect ratio
            float ratioX = (float)maxWidth / (float)originalWidth;
            float ratioY = (float)maxHeight / (float)originalHeight;
            float ratio = Math.Min(ratioX, ratioY);

            // New width and height based on aspect ratio
            newWidth = (int)(originalWidth * ratio);
            newHeight = (int)(originalHeight * ratio);
        }
        // Convert other formats (including CMYK) to RGB.
        Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

        // Draws the image in the specified size with quality mode set to HighQuality
        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
        {
            graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            graphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
        }

        // Get an ImageCodecInfo object that represents the JPEG codec.
        ImageCodecInfo imageCodecInfo = this.GetEncoderInfo(ImageFormat.Jpeg);

        // Create an Encoder object for the Quality parameter.
        Encoder encoder = Encoder.Quality;

        // Create an EncoderParameters object. 
        EncoderParameters encoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);

        // Save the image as a JPEG file with quality level.
        EncoderParameter encoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(encoder, quality);
        encoderParameters.Param[0] = encoderParameter;
        newImage.Save(pathWithName, imageCodecInfo, encoderParameters);

        iWidth = newWidth;
        iHeight = newHeight;
        return pathWithName;
    }
```

Comment: Does the original source image affect the results?

Comment: I would imagine that the conversion from CMYK to RGB may have a play in this.

Comment: Also, the original image might have an embedded ICC profile, but not the result. Thus a smart enough viewer will adjust the colors for the original, but not the result.

Comment: These comments make sense but is there anyway to solve the issue?